# Spring for Cassandra-Unit throws an exception in CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, cassandra

I am trying to write my unit tests with Spring for Cassandra and getting an exception inside CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener

WARN  o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitTestExecutionListener@1787f2a0] to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void com.emc.polaris.admin.persistence.cassandra.RolesManagementTest.test() throws com.emc.polaris.tools.exceptions.ObjectAccessException], instance [com.emc.polaris.admin.persistence.cassandra.RolesManagementTest@7de62196], exception [java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but class was expected]

Although it is marked as WARN in the stack trace I think it prevents my test from running. I am using Spring 4 (tried 4.0.3 to 4.0.6) and Java 8. Did anyone encounter this kind of exception before?

Comment: seeing this as well, I think it's an incompatibly of spring-cassandra-unit with spring 4, which was developed with 3.2

Comment: @Nitzan Volman The issue is solved with in version 2.0.2.2. which is compiled against Spring 4. I am still getting a series of exceptions after all tests are executed. It does not affect the test results though.